# Backbone: getting the html code of a view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In order to write the HTML code of social icons (Twitter, Linkedin, etc) to a textarea so that the user can use that code elsewhere, I would like to get the HTML code of the view element, but I'm having some issues. To help illustrate this better, here is the code that creates the view:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    var _ = require('underscore');
    var GridControlView = require('pb/views/grid-control');
    var SocialiconsControlDialog = require('pb/views/socialicons-control-dialog');
    var template = require('text!pb/templates/socialicons-grid-control.html');

    var SocialiconsGridControlView = GridControlView.extend({
         template: _.template(template)
        ,templateVars: {
            partials: {
                 facebook:   require('text!pb/templates/socialicons-grid-control-facebook.html')
                ,twitter:    require('text!pb/templates/socialicons-grid-control-twitter.html')
                ,googleplus: require('text!pb/templates/socialicons-grid-control-googleplus.html')
                ,pinterest:  require('text!pb/templates/socialicons-grid-control-pinterest.html')
                ,linkedin:   require('text!pb/templates/socialicons-grid-control-linkedin.html')
            }
        }
        ,control_dialog: SocialiconsControlDialog
    });

    return SocialiconsGridControlView;
});
```

And, for example, the Linkedin template looks like this:

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js?<%- t.cache_buster %>" type="text/javascript">lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-counter="<%- t.linkedin_option_countmode %>"></script>
```

What I would like to retrieve, is the parsed template code as text, something such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js?0.4670609195438331">
<script data-counter="top" type="IN/Share+init">
```

But using something such as:

`control_view.render().$el.innerHTML;`, `control_view.render().$el.html().text()` or `control_view.render().$el.html().replace(/<\/?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>/ig, "");` doesn't return text; it returns the full HTML, and produces a Linkedin icon (when I just want the text to be written to a textarea).

Any thoughts?

Update **

I noticed that the code `control_view.render().$el` is working correctly on other places of the application, and returning HTML code, but for some reason in this view where I'm trying it doesn't. The code seems to break at:

```
$control = control_view.render().el;
```

and in the console I get an error which is:

> TypeError: t is undefined - underscore-min.js (line 3)

Comment: Can you use control_view.render().el (instead of the jQuery reference $el)?

Comment: Yes, but the result is the same.

Comment: I updated the question with some extra information, which I hope helps :/

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.outerHTML` property of the `$el`.

```
var html = $('<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js?0.4670609195438331">' +
'<script data-counter="top" type="IN/Share+init">');
var text = html[0].outerHTML;
$('textarea').val(text);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92hkD/1/)

Comment: That would be cheating... The whole point is to retrieve the html that you just inputted as text. That needs to come from the view, because it could be any of a wide array of social icons, with a wide array of different options.